# Managing resources in a Python project

Tags: python, resources, setuptools, distutils, decoupling

I have a Python project in which I am using many non-code files. Currently these are all images, but I might use other kinds of files in the future. What would be a good scheme for storing and referencing these files?

I considered just making a folder "resources" in the main directory, but there is a problem; Some images are used from within sub-packages of my project. Storing these images that way would lead to coupling, which is a disadvantage.

Also, I need a way to access these files which is independent on what my current directory is.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You may want to use `pkg_resources` library that comes with `setuptools`.

For example, I've made up a quick little package `"proj"` to illustrate the resource organization scheme I'd use:

```
proj/setup.py
proj/proj/__init__.py
proj/proj/code.py
proj/proj/resources/__init__.py
proj/proj/resources/images/__init__.py
proj/proj/resources/images/pic1.png
proj/proj/resources/images/pic2.png
```

Notice how I keep all resources in a separate subpackage.

`"code.py"` shows how `pkg_resources` is used to refer to the resource objects:

```
from pkg_resources import resource_string, resource_listdir

# Itemize data files under proj/resources/images:
print resource_listdir('proj.resources.images', '')
# Get the data file bytes:
print resource_string('proj.resources.images', 'pic2.png').encode('base64')
```

If you run it, you get:

```
['__init__.py', '__init__.pyc', 'pic1.png', 'pic2.png']
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE ...
```

If you need to treat a resource as a fileobject, use `resource_stream()`.

The code accessing the resources may be anywhere within the subpackage structure of your project, it just needs to refer to subpackage containing the images by full name: `proj.resources.images`, in this case.

Here's `"setup.py"`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='proj',
      packages=find_packages(),
      package_data={'': ['*.png']})
```

*Caveat:*
To test things "locally", that is w/o installing the package first, you'll have to invoke your test scripts from directory that has `setup.py`. If you're in the same directory as `code.py`, Python won't know about `proj` package. So things like `proj.resources` won't resolve.

Comment: Well, the disadvantages here are too much. Isn't there a sane simple way to pack resources with Python projects?

Comment: I know of only 2 widely supported ways (they ain't simple unfortunately): 

1) `distutils`-way (standard): the documentation leaves accessing resource files as an exercise to the reader (probably because they think path manipulations relative to `__file__` are all one needs).

2) `setuptools`-way (superset of `distutils`), described above.

Comment: Surprised this hasn't been brought up already but shouldn't it be `decode` not `encode` for the output of `resource_string`?

Comment: @archeezee this post is from Python 2.x times. `resource_string` returns raw byte representation of `pic2.png` in this case, which is not ideal if you want to print it :) hence the base64 encoding call.

Comment: This seems unsatisfying because it necessarily pollutes the "package space". For example, in your example `resources` *must* be a subdirectory of `proj`, simply because otherwise when someone pip installs my project I will pollute their package space with `resources` (`import resources` will get them my resources directory). Very irritating that where I put my data has to be constrained like this just because Python has coupled it together with the totally unrelated concept of source code packages.

Answer (score 19):

The new way of doing this is with [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.resources). For Python versions older than 3.7 you can add a dependency to `importlib_resources` and do something like

```py
from importlib_resources import files


def get_resource(module: str, name: str) -> str:
    """Load a textual resource file."""
    return files(module).joinpath(name).read_text(encoding="utf-8")
```

If your resources live inside the `foo/resources` sub-module, you would then use `get_resource` like so

```py
resource_text = get_resource('foo.resources', 'myresource')
```

Comment: Since 3.9 this seems to be `importlib.resources.files(package)` now ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.resources.files)).

Answer (score 6):

You can always have a separate "resources" folder in each subpackage which needs it, and use `os.path` functions to get to these from the `__file__` values of your subpackages. To illustrate what I mean, I created the following `__init__.py` file in three locations:

```
c:\temp\topp        (top-level package)
c:\temp\topp\sub1   (subpackage 1)
c:\temp\topp\sub2   (subpackage 2)
```

Here's the `__init__.py` file:

```
import os.path
resource_path = os.path.join(os.path.split(__file__)[0], "resources")
print resource_path
```

In c:\temp\work, I create an app, topapp.py, as follows:

```
import topp
import topp.sub1
import topp.sub2
```

This respresents the application using the `topp` package and subpackages. Then I run it:

```
C:\temp\work>topapp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\temp\work\topapp.py", line 1, in 
    import topp
ImportError: No module named topp
```

That's as expected. We set the PYTHONPATH to simulate having our package on the path:

```
C:\temp\work>set PYTHONPATH=c:\temp

C:\temp\work>topapp
c:\temp\topp\resources
c:\temp\topp\sub1\resources
c:\temp\topp\sub2\resources
```

As you can see, the resource paths resolved correctly to the location of the actual (sub)packages on the path.

**Update:** [Here](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/data_files)'s the relevant py2exe documentation.

Comment: But what about when you want to py2exe the whole thing?

Comment: I was not talking about how to pack the resources with the code. I was talking about the fact that `__file__` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

@ pycon2009, there was a presentation on distutils and setuptools. You can find all of the videos here

[Eggs and Buildout Deployment in Python - Part 1](http://pycon.blip.tv/file/2061520/)

[Eggs and Buildout Deployment in Python - Part 2](http://pycon.blip.tv/file/2061678/)

[Eggs and Buildout Deployment in Python - Part 3](http://pycon.blip.tv/file/2061724/)

In these videos, they describe how to include static resources in your package. I believe its in part 2.

With setuptools, you can define dependancies, this would allow you to have 2 packages that use resources from 3rd package.

Setuptools also gives you a standard way of accessing these resources and allows you to use relative paths inside of your packages, which eliminates the need to worry about where your packages are installed.