# Load CSV File from specific package

Tags: python

I'd like to load an CSV file from another package.

In my case I want to call csv.reader in the reader.py and load / open there the Pers1_fb.csv from the data package.

My intention is to use the data package as ressource folder, similar to Java

How can I archieve this?
I am on Python 3.9

My folder structure is like this:

```
- Project_Folder
   |
   |- main
        |- __init__.py
        |- reader.py
    

   |- data
        |- __init__.py
        |- Pers1_fb.csv
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Managing resources in a Python project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395593/managing-resources-in-a-python-project)

Comment: not really because it features a deprecated way of achieving this, I guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can determine the path to the `data` folder as one relative to the built-in `__file__` attribute (which is the path to the currently executing script/module `.py` file). This can easily be done with the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) module:

Code in `reader.py`:

```
from pathlib import Path

data_folder_path = (Path(__file__) / '../../data' ).resolve()
csv_file_path = data_folder_path / 'Pers1_fb.csv'
print(csv_file_path)  # -> 'Project_Folder/data/Pers1_fb.csv'
```

Comment: thank you :) this is what I searched for

Answer (score 0):

I'd say just get the current directoy, go up one file level and then navigate as usual from there. Using the `os` for example:

```py
base = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())
data_path = os.path.join(base, 'data')
```

I'm sure that this can be done more elegantly with `Pathlib` too!

Comment: Using the current directory is unreliable because it often isn't the same as the script being executed, depending on how it was run.

Comment: I was assuming the exact file structure posted in the question, but I see your point.

Comment: The file structure isn't that relevant to the point I was trying to make. I meant for example that the script could have been executed from some arbitrary folder simply by specifying a full path to it: i.e. via `python Project_Folder/main/reader.py` without changing the current directory.