# How can I write a setup.py that ensures a non-code (data) file is at the same relative path from my script as in my repository?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-packaging

When I'm developing a project, and a script `script.py` needs access to some data file `data.txt`, I will usually write something like this:

```py
path = Path(__file__).parent.parent / "resources" / "text" / "data.txt"
```

I then commit `data.txt` to source control, and when people clone the repo, everything will work. This works nicely until the project matures to the point that I want to write a `setup.py` to let people just install it straight from the repo with pip. At this point, I can't figure out how to tell `setup.py` to just put the `resources` folder in the "same place" in the package as it is in my repository. I've looked into `package_data`, `data_files` and `MANIFEST.in` but I haven't been able to get any solution working. How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Managing resources in a Python project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395593/managing-resources-in-a-python-project)

Comment: @Sören No. It's still not clear from those answers how to access the file from my code, given only its relative path.